# Extract specific value from a property from a map

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following data:

```
const data = [
        {
          Zone: 'Airport',
          Lane: 'AIRDEL',
          Capacity: '90',
          Status: '80',
          Spaces: '10',
          LastAuditedOn: 'due',
          AuditedBy: 'Ross',
          FirstCollection: '-',
          LastCollection: '-',
        },
        {
          Zone: 'Arrivals',
          Lane: '4',
          Capacity: '10',
          Status: '0',
          Spaces: '10',
          LastAuditedOn: '-',
          AuditedBy: '-',
          FirstCollection: '9:00PM',
          LastCollection: '01:00AM',
        },
        {
          Zone: 'Unknown',
          Lane: 'BHX_HOLD1',
          Capacity: '80',
          Status: '40',
          Spaces: '40',
          LastAuditedOn: 'due',
          AuditedBy: 'Max',
          FirstCollection: '-',
          LastCollection: '-',
        },
]
```

and I am currently trying to extract the data based off the properties (zone, lane, capacity) as an example.

```
const multiHeaderBy = 'Zone';
data.forEach((key) => {
   console.log(key.find(multiHeaderBy))
});
```

I expect values `arrivals, airport, unknown` to appear in the `console.log` but i get undefined.

Ideas?

Comment: Not sure how you get undefined, `key.find` isn't a function because `find` doesn't work on objects.

Comment: `data.map(el => el.Zone)` will return an array with those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods like:

```js
const data=[{Zone:'Airport',Lane:'AIRDEL',Capacity:'90',Status:'80',Spaces:'10',LastAuditedOn:'due',AuditedBy:'Ross',FirstCollection:'-',LastCollection:'-',},{Zone:'Arrivals',Lane:'4',Capacity:'10',Status:'0',Spaces:'10',LastAuditedOn:'-',AuditedBy:'-',FirstCollection:'9:00PM',LastCollection:'01:00AM',},{Zone:'Unknown',Lane:'BHX_HOLD1',Capacity:'80',Status:'40',Spaces:'40',LastAuditedOn:'due',AuditedBy:'Max',FirstCollection:'-',LastCollection:'-',}];

const multiHeaderBy = 'Zone';
var txt = data.map(x => x[multiHeaderBy]);
console.log(txt.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map function to get array using key

```
var valueArr = data.map(e=>e.Zone);

console.log(valueArr) // ["Airport", "Arrivals", "Unknown"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [] backet instead of find function. [] backet is used to get the value from an object using dynamic key.

```
    const multiHeaderBy = 'Zone';
data.forEach((key) => {
   console.log(key[multiHeaderBy])
});
```